# Mongoexport with cluster throws i/o timeout error

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Just upgraded to **mongo 3.0**, but `mongoexport` gives us a the following error: *"Failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:27020: i/o timeout"* after outputting some documents (not always the same amount). `mongoexport` is connecting to a sharded cluster of 4 standalone mongod servers with 3 mongod config servers

> [root@SRV]$ mongoexport --host
>   localhost:27022,localhost:27021,localhost:27020 --db horus
>   --collection users --type json --fields _id | wc -l
>
> 2015-03-09T12:41:19.198-0600  connected to: 
>   localhost:27022,localhost:27021,localhost:27020
>
> 2015-03-09T12:41:22.570-0600  Failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:27020: i/o
>   timeout
>
> 15322

The versions we are using are:

> [root@MONGODB01-SRV]# mongo --version  MongoDB shell version: 3.0.0
>
> [root@SRV]$ mongoexport --version  mongoexport version: 3.0.0 git
>   version: e35a2e87876251835fcb60f5eb0c29baca04bc5e
>
> [root@SRV]$ mongos --version  MongoS version 3.0.0 starting: pid=47359
>   port=27017 64-bit host=SRV (--help for usage) git version:
>   a841fd6394365954886924a35076691b4d149168 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
>   1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 build sys info: Linux ip-10-181-61-91 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49

Tried with a 2.6 `mongoexport` in another server against our **mongod3.0** and **mongos3.0** and works fine

Comment: This is the second time I've seen a report like this, and there have been issues like this with the Go driver in the past - the tools were rewritten in Go for 3.0. Could you open a ticket in the MongoDB [TOOLS](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS) project with a description of the issue so the engineers can look at it?

Comment: I did, 3.0.1 should have a fix for this (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-652) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I wanted to answer. Maybe this answer will help one of us. It might be caused by someone else trying to write to the collection you are writing. I had a smilar problem. After a long research I realised that a user with higher role was trying to write in the sametime and because his/her role is more important than mine ones request were done and mine are given IO exception.

Answer (score -1):

Try closing the ports first: eg. `killall -9 node`